# Find offset that minimizes squared difference between two vectors of different size

Tags: c++, performance, memoization

I am working on a project where the hotspot is some code that is supposed to find an offset, such that the squared differences between a reference vector and a given vector becomes minimal. The core function is this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
typedef std::vector<double> vect_d

double sqDiffSum(const vect_d& ref, const vect_d& x,int offset){
    size_t scale = ref.size() / x.size(); // ref.size() is always n*x.size()
    double sum = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    for (size_t i=0;i<x.size();i++){
        for (size_t j=0;j<scale;j++){
            int bin = i*scale + j - offset;
            if (bin >= 0 && bin < (int)ref.size()){
                double diff = ref[bin] - x[i];
                sum += diff * diff;
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    return sum / counter;
}
```

This is called from some minimization routine, that (for now) I dont want to change. It varies the `offset` to get the minimum `sqDiffSum`. I know that I could probably do the task faster by using a FFT, but for now I want to see how much I can get out of the current approach. I could already make it faster (roughly x2.5) by adding some memoization:

```
double callSqDiffSum(const vect_d& ref, const vect_d& x,int offset,bool firstCall){
    static std::map<int,double> memo;
    if (firstCall){ memo.clear(); }
    else {
        std::map<int,double>::iterator found = memo.find(offset);
        if (found != memo.end()){
            return found->second;
        }
    }    
    double result = sqDiffSum(ref,x,offset);
    memo[offset] = result;
    return result;
}
```

However, it is still too slow. There are several points that in principle I could optimize, but for each I have my doubts whether it will bring any benefit:

- The reference vector `ref` is actually always the same, thus I could avoid passing it around at all.
- The size of the vectors is always the same, so actually there is no need for `std::vector`, but if possible I would like to avoid c-style arrays and I dont expect too much improvement by not using vectors here.
- The innermost loop has some branching, that could be avoided

**Is there anything that comes to your mind to make this more efficient? Is my assumption that the above points are not really worth to change wrong?**

Please note that this is pre-C++11.

Comment: @BCdotWEB ups yes completely agree

Comment: You could probably give a try and ask for advice on math.stackexchange.com . Looking for minimum values between two variables sounds like derivative to me (i.e. a calculus problem). If `f(x)` is your first vector and `g(x)` is your second vector, you want to get the minimum value of `h(x) = (f(x)-g(x))^2)`. I'm not sure, but maybe you can get away with just calculating the derivative `h'(x)` . That would go from O(n^2) to O(1).

Comment: @ChatterOne Actually I already asked a question related to this problem on math.stackexchange. A better algorithm uses convolution via FFT. However, for now I wanted to see how far I can get with my current approach (mainly because there is some legacy code and I have to be very careful in changing the algorithm).

Answer (score 2):

Without changing the algorithm, the only things I can see by having a look at the assembly of `sqDiffSum`:

- read `x[i]` only once in the outer loop (i.e `const double x_i = x[i]` and then use `x_i` instead). You'll get a small win by not having to fetch it whenever you enter the `if`.
- compute once `i * scale - offset` in the outer loop because this invariant. But latest gcc and clang seem smart enough to figure this out themselves.

Also, you might want to test `std::unordered_map`.

edit: whenever `bin >= ref.size()`, you know that it will be for all the next `j`. Maybe you even replace `j` by `bin` running (before morning coffee) when \$offset >= i \cdot scale\$ and \$\frac{i \cdot ref\_size}{x\_size} + offset < ref\_size\$

Comment: thanks for the suggestions I might accept this once i tried it out, but I will be on holidays for the next two weeks :)